# Installing libpng on ubuntu

Tags: makefile, libpng

I am installing libpng on linux system, I am using the following steps as mentioned in the INSTALL file.

```
cp scripts/makefile.std makefile
cp scripts/pnglibconf.h.prebuilt pnglibconf.h
```

The above two commands work fine, then I run `make` , it shows the following message: No rule to make target 'png.h' , needed by 'png.o' . Stop.

I don't know how to fix it, Please explain how to install it.

Comment: perhaps you could include a link to the instructions you are following?

Answer (score 0):

[Looks like the same problem like yours](http://www.experts-exchange.com/OS/Linux/Q_21823693.html). Proposed solution:

> In the libpng source directory, look for png.h "e.g. find . -type f -name png.h -print".
>   Manually copy this file to /usr/include